# How do I GroupBy in Spring Data Mongodb without Aggregation?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I have a data like below, and I want to group that data by the type, I'm using `spring-data-mongodb` .

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58a5518aace6132a88309d98"),
        "type" : "SMS",
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58a5518bace6132a88309d99"),
        "type" : "PUSH_NOTIFICATION",
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58a5519aace6132a0094d7df"),
        "type" : "SMS",
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58a5519aace6132a0094d7e0"),
        "type" : "PUSH_NOTIFICATION",
    }
]
```

I'm using this method and won't work.

```
GroupByResults<Queuing> results = mongoTemplate.group("queuing",
                GroupBy.key("type"), Queuing.class);
```

Anyone know the best and clear way to do this grouping using `spring-data-mongodb`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for `group` operation.

```
GroupByResults<Queuing> results = mongoTemplate.group("queuing",
            GroupBy.key("type").initialDocument("{}").reduceFunction("function(doc, prev) {}"),
            Queuing.class);
```

More information here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.group.example